# Is there a specific name for manipulating English language this way

Tags: word-choice, word-play, pun

Few days ago a football player named Harry Kane showed great performance, next day the newspaper posted "Hurricane beats Arsenal"

Everyday I pass by a money/cash/loans shop that shows an advert "YOU ARE NOT (ALOAN)"

Is there a specific name for similar cute manipulation?

Comment: [...aside from being a time-traveling wunderkind, "**Hurricane**" Harry "Sugar" Kane a.k.a. The man of a thousand nicknames, is a 19, soon to be 20, year-old footballer](http://cartilagefreecaptain.sbnation.com/2013/6/20/4448158/tottenham-hotspur-prospect-rankings-harry-kane-youth-academy-spurs). He's been given that ***alliterative*** nickname by fans/reporters, as well as the ***associative*** "Sugar-cane".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Pun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pun)? It would be the most common way to describe it - though there could be a more accurate term.

Comment: I would call it punning or [wordplay](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wordplay).